# Is a IEEE student member counted as a member in a submission to a transaction?

Tags: publications, journals, terminology, ieee

I am going to submit a paper to a IEEE transaction. I am a student member of IEEE. In the auther line of the paper, do I append "IEEE, Member", "IEEE, Student Member" or nothing after my name?

Comment: I think "IEEE, Student Member" is the best choice.

Comment: Why do you want to hide your affiliation with your university?

Comment: @user13107: IEEE stupidly insists that all authors who are IEEE members identify themselves as such on the title page.  The authors' university/industry affiliations are listed on the title page as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have published in the IEEE and "Student Member, IEEE, " is what you should write after your name (if you care to), because you're **not** a full member. Note that it doesn't have any benefits to it — you don't get a discount/additional copies/favorable review/faster review/muffins/... nada. It is exactly the same as if you had listed nothing at all.

Perhaps the only advantage might be for senior members, who want visibility (as a member) in order to be elected a Fellow, and for Fellows, if they want to show off (but by that point, you probably don't care).

Comment: Having said that, I don't know why you're asking such a localized question on this site. Go consult your journal's manuscript guidelines article for such minor details.